# I cant download the app when it is shared from internal app sharing from google play store

Tags: internal-app-sharing

I am trying to test my app using internal app testing under setup menu in play store

I deployed the aab file there and got downloadable link

Choose who can download and install shared apps

Anyone you shared the link with can download- I chose this option so that whomever I share the file with can install and test

When I run the url in mobile browser it takes me to google play store and asks me to enable internal app sharing, I did that and after that It asks me to download the app at that time there is a pop up called cant download the app

Please fine the screen and help me solve this issue

[image]

Thank you

Comment: I have the same issue with an AAB file distributed with fastlane. I think i'm having a probem with applicationId, so there is a mismatch between my app update the and app set up in Google Play Console.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to *Clear storage* for the Google Play Store app to get pass the "Can't download" dialog.

Answer (score 1):

After seeing this "Can't download" dialog, I did **Force stop the Google Play** app, and **wait for 20-30 minutes**.
For me, it started working (downloading), after that.

Comment: Force-stopping Google Play worked for me